# ¿Cómo puedo inspeccionar las opciones de un select en Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css

¿Cómo puedo inspeccionar las opciones de un select en Firefox? Necesito ver la tipografia que se esta utilizando en las opciones del select.

Comment: Si quieres las opciones mas personalizables por un select, por mi parte yo usaría boostrap, tomando de una librería o manualmente haría un Dropdown, y la interactividad lo hago con js

Comment: Solamente quiero inspeccionar el elemento option dentro de un select @AlbertArias

Comment: Te refieres al inspector de elementos??

Comment: Si, ya que cuando abro el select y quiero inspeccionar las opciones dentro del select , le doy click en inspeccionar elemento y se cierra el dropdown @DavElsanto

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con inspeccionar. Quieres leer algun atributo,clase, value?

Comment: Quiero inspeccionar la option dentro del select para ver el font-family de la option. @HernánGarcia

Answer (score 1):

En si el principio es el mismo independiente del navegador, selecciona el elemento html(en este caso el option del select) en el inspector de elementos(click derecho inspeccionar elemento) dirigente algún `option`, y busca la propiedad que necesites.

[image: Safari inspector]

Y directamente en firefox.

[image: firefox inspector]

Comment: Gracias, no se por que razón en Chrome tengo la tipografia correcta y en firefox me aparece otro tipo de letra.... alguna idea?

Comment: Pueda que en el navegador que siempre usas los estilos del css permanezcan en caché prueba recargando todo el contenido con `ctrl` + `shift` + `r` de esta forma se resetean los estilos que puedan estar almacenados en caché